# How to remove Java Resources error in Eclipse maven project inspite of being every java files/jsp files/xml files are correct with no errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

Below is the error I am getting. I am surprised if I make new project and copy all files it starts working.

What can be missing with my current project?

[image: Problem Image with Error]

Comment: try to have a look at the Problems view in Eclipse. Window > Show view > Problems

Comment: right click on project --> properties ,  Java Build Path navigate to Source tab. You might be missing here some thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try right click on project `Update project configuration.`

Most likely your maven project is not being recognized. If need first convert to maven project using right click and `Convert to Maven project` followed by right click on project "`Update project configuration`".